# Create "fake" user in my ASPNETUsers Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I am running some Integration Tests and I wish to create a "fake" user in my `ASPNETUsers` table.

I am trying to do the following with no luck.

So I have the Setup as follows :-

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    var basePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
    var projectPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(basePath, "../../../../SportsStore2.Tests"));

    var server = new TestServer(Utils.GetHostBuilder(new string[] { })
        .UseContentRoot(projectPath)
        .UseEnvironment("Development")
        .UseStartup<Startup>());

    _client = server.CreateClient();
}
```

and then the Insert is as follows :-

```
var registerViewModel = new RegisterViewModel
{
    Email = "test@test.com",
    ConfirmPassword = "testing12345?",
    Password = "testing12345?"
};
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var postResponseASPNETUser = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:49406/Account/Register", registerViewModel);
var createdASPNETUser = await postResponseASPNETUser.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

However I am getting a 400 response, Bad Request.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Does the response not contain more detail beyond Bad Request?

Comment: well this is what I am getting :--  RequestMessage {Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://localhost:49406/Account/Register', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.ObjectContent`1[SportsStore2.API.Models.AccountViewModels.RegisterViewModel], Headers:
{
  Accept: application/json
  Host: localhost:49406
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}} System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage

Comment: nothing that stands out though

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the api directly, since I had no luck and could not find why it was not returning a correct response, I decided to go another route, and basically created another Create Action inside my UsersController as follows:-

```
    [HttpPost("Create")]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] User user)
    {
        if (user == null)
            return BadRequest();

        var result = _usersService.Add(user, m => m.Name == user.Name);
        if (result)
        {
            return CreatedAtRoute("GetUsers", new { id = user.Id }, user);

        }
        return BadRequest("Item not added");
    }

    [HttpPost("CreateAspNetUsers")]
    public IActionResult CreateAspNetUsers([FromBody] RegisterViewModel registerViewModel)
    {
        if (registerViewModel == null)
            return BadRequest();

        var result = _aspNetUsersService.Add(registerViewModel, m => m.Name == registerViewModel.Email);
        if (result)
        {
            return CreatedAtRoute("GetUsers", registerViewModel);
        }
        return BadRequest("Item not added");
    }
```

This works fine and is giving me the result I was after.